# Return Record With Earliest Date

Tags: sql, netezza, aginity

I am using `Aginity Workbench` with a database on `Netezza` and I am trying to return the record with the earliest date based on it featuring an `IS` code in any one of three (serviceability) columns.  There are multiple records for one `ICS_UID`, but I just want to return the record where the earliest occurrence of it having an `IS` code.

Below is the code I have been trying to use but it seems to be returning all instances of where a record has an `IS` code and not the selection of `ICS_UID`'s in the where clause. Grateful for any help or advice.

```
SELECT 
ICS _UID, min(MOVEMENT_DATE) as MOVEMENT_DATE, CURRENT_A_SERVICABILITY_CODE, CURRENT_B_SERVICABILITY_CODE, 
CURRENT_C_SERVICABILITY_CODE 
FROM 
HUB_MOVEMENT
WHERE 
ICS_UID IN (317517607,317962513,etc,etc…)
AND CURRENT_A_SERVICABILITY_CODE = 'IS' OR CURRENT_B_SERVICABILITY_CODE = 'IS' OR CURRENT_C_SERVICABILITY_CODE = 'IS'
GROUP BY 
ICS_UID, CURRENT_A_SERVICABILITY_CODE,
CURRENT_B_SERVICABILITY_CODE,
CURRENT_C_SERVICABILITY_CODE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `GROUP BY`.  If you want one record, then:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM HUB_MOVEMENT m
WHERE ICS_UID IN (317517607,317962513,etc,etc…) AND
      'IS' IN (CURRENT_A_SERVICABILITY_CODE, CURRENT_B_SERVICABILITY_CODE , CURRENT_C_SERVICABILITY_CODE)
ORDER BY MOVEMENT_DATE
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want one row per `ICS_UID`, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ICS_UID ORDER BY MOVEMENT_DATE) as seqnum
      FROM HUB_MOVEMENT m
      WHERE ICS_UID IN (317517607,317962513,etc,etc…) AND
            'IS' IN (CURRENT_A_SERVICABILITY_CODE, CURRENT_B_SERVICABILITY_CODE , CURRENT_C_SERVICABILITY_CODE)
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Nice use of 'IS' IN (.....), was thinking of the same thing to shorten the repeated or statements

Comment: Thank you! i used your second example and it works perfectly! I am an sql noob, but thought i was down the wrong road with group by.